# I need help converting legacy async script to current API model

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

About TypeScript and [Converting legacy async scripts to the current model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/excel-async-model#converting-legacy-async-scripts-to-the-current-model)

I am trying to convert an async script to the current model, but I am unable to determine a part of the code:

```
async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
sheets.load("items/name");
```

I need to get the spreadsheet collection and load the name property of each spreadsheet.

it should be like this, but in the third line I can't load the properties:

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  var sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  sheets.?????;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the improved OfficeScript API, you do not need the .load function at all anymore. To access all the worksheet names, you just need code like this:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let worksheetArray = workbook.getWorksheets();
    worksheetArray.forEach( ( sheet ) => {
      console.log( sheet.getName());
    });
}
```

The first line an array of all the sheet objects. The `.forEach()` method on the array then allows you to cycle through all of those objects, and you can call the `getName()` method on any of those sheets to get the name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help Jim, it is perfect. Regards